# Linked list problem with while loop, should I use continue?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have to print out every unique integer in a linked list, it turned out the it's not printing anything.I tried using continue and remove the else but by doing that I only get the first unique item in the linked list. My question is that does continue end the loop or just skip the current iteration? If it only skips the current one, say i have a linked list that looks like 1->5, why am I only getting 1 printed here? Thanks in advance.

```
 struct node {
    int data; 
    struct node* next; 
 }


void printList(struct node *head)  // print out unique items of the list
{

    struct node *ptr = head;
    struct node *prev = NULL;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {

        if(prev->data == ptr->data)
        {
            prev = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;

        }else{
        printf("%d", ptr->data);
        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `struct node` look like?

Comment: `break` breaks out of the loop, `continue` ... continues the loop. That's very basic C knowledge covered in every C text book.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you run it? It looks like you should to me, since you'll be dereferencing a null pointer the first time you evaluate `prev->data`.

Comment: Aside: the code could be much simplifed by a slight reordering and the removal of the duplication of  `prev = ptr; ptr = ptr->next;` which are needed whether or not there was a match found.

Comment: struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}; here's the struct node

Comment: @AlexH you should add that code to the question so that everyone can see it right away. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The code as written generates a segmentation fault because you're referencing a NULL pointer. In this line:

```
if(prev->data == ptr->data)
```

Since `prev` is NULL to start, `prev->data` will dereference the NULL pointer and crash the program.  That doesn't explain why you saw it not printing the last element, but the code as written is definitely broken.

Try this:

```
void printList(struct node *head)  // print out unique items of the list
{

    struct node *ptr = head;
    struct node *prev = NULL;

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        // Check if prev is NULL, and if not, that prev->data and ptr->data
        // don't match.
        if (! prev || ptr->data != prev->data)
        {
            printf("%d\n", ptr->data);
        }

        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Could you explain what does !prev stand for?

Comment: `!prev` is a short way of saying `prev == NULL`. :-)